# Backup of Exchange Server 2003,2007 using VSS API's

Tags: windows, backup, exchange-server, volume-shadow-service

Can Exchange Server 2003 and 2007 be backup up using VSS API's that are provided for exchange 2010?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, please refer to [Exchange 2007 and Windows 2008: Online Exchange Backup (part 6 of 7)](http://theessentialexchange.com/blogs/michael/archive/2009/01/26/exchange-2007-and-windows-2008-online-exchange-backup-part-6-of-7.aspx).

Get the edb, chk & log file paths using `get-StorageGroup`, `get-MailboxDatabase` & `get-PublicFolderDatabase` for Exchange 2007 or `get-MailboxDatabase` & `get-PublicFolderDatabase` for Exchange 2010,

and do the usual VSS stuff to copy them.

Make sure to signal VSS backup success to purge the log files.